# How to influence the order of methodes in reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I want to create a Swingtable with a dynamic Layout, regarding the class data that is set as sources.
To be more specific:
I have a class with multiple attributes. When creating the table, I want to do it, so that the table looks: "which public getFunction with returntyp String are available" and use the attributes behind this functions as Columnnames and later also as source for the rows.

That is working at the moment.

My problem now is:
How can I ensure a specific order of my Columns with this approach?
for example i have a column "ID","callsign","categorie".
I want to display them in this order.
No metter how i order the methodes in sourceCode, the columns are allways in the same order ("ID","categorie","callsign").

```
        java.lang.reflect.Method methodes[] = null;
        methodes = classObjectOfT.getMethods();
        List<String> tempList=new ArrayList<String>();
        for (java.lang.reflect.Method m: methodes)
        {
            if (m.getReturnType().equals(String.class)&&m.getName().startsWith("get"))
            {
                tempList.add(m.getName().substring(3));
            }
        }
        columnNames=(String[]) tempList.toArray(new String[tempList.size()]);
```

above is the code i use for retriving the columnames.

A workaround would be to name the attributes/getMethodes "ID_00","Callsign_01","Categorie_02" and do the ordering by using the last 2 chars of the String, but that would be rather ugly and i'm searching for a cleaner solution.

Comment: If this is Java 8, you can get a more elegant solution using lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating an annotation which you would use to define the order and even more meta data for your table columns, for example a label:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface TableColumn {
    String label();
    int order();
}
```

Then retrieve them like this:

```
public Set<Method> findTableColumsGetters(Class<TestTableData> clazz) {
    Set<Method> methods = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Method>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Method o1, Method o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1.getAnnotation(TableColumn.class).order())
                    .compareTo(o2.getAnnotation(TableColumn.class).order());
        }
    });
    for(Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
        if(method.isAnnotationPresent(TableColumn.class)) {
            methods.add(method);
        }
    }
    return methods;
}
```

Here is some testings:

Test table data

```
static class TestTableData {
    private String id, callsign, categorie;

    @TableColumn(label = "Caterogy", order = 3)
    public String getCategorie() {
        return categorie;
    }

    public void setCategorie(String categorie) {
        this.categorie = categorie;
    }

    @TableColumn(label = "Call sign", order = 2)
    public String getCallsign() {
        return callsign;
    }

    public void setCallsign(String callsign) {
        this.callsign = callsign;
    }

    @TableColumn(label = "ID", order = 1)
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void findTableColumsGetters() {
    Set<Method> getters = findTableColumsGetters(TestTableData.class);
    for(Method getter : getters) {
        TableColumn annotation = getter.getAnnotation(TableColumn.class);
        System.out.printf("%d %s (%s)%n", annotation.order(), annotation.label(), getter.getName());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 ID (getId)
2 Call sign (getCallsign)
3 Caterogy (getCategorie)
```

I would suggest though that you don't retrieve the annotation reach time you need info from it, instead create a Metadata class for your methods where you put everyting including the method itself while you are performing the search.